# Ionic2 Tabs after logout still showed up in navigation page, what i missed here?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic2, ionic-tabs

Here is what i trying to achieve, i already log in into my aplication, but when i logout, the tab is still there until i refresh my page in my login screen, i want it gone from my login screen when i logout how, what i missed here? Here is what i do :

my app.component.ts :

```
export class MyApp {
  public rootPage: any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {

    if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") === null) {
      console.log("not logged in");
        this.rootPage = LoginPagePage;
    } else {
      console.log("already logged in");
        this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    }

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

below is my tabs.ts :

```
export class TabsPage {

  public tab1Root: any;
  public tab2Root: any;
  public tab3Root: any;

  constructor() {
    this.tab1Root = HomePage;
    this.tab2Root = AboutPage;
    this.tab3Root = ExplorePage;
  }

}
```

then here is my tabs.html :

when i do that, it appear normal when first load, the tabs doesn't show up. Then after i logged in, i do set

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
```

here is my logout code :

```
  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPagePage);
  }
```

there i already setRoot into my LoginPagePage, why still the tab appear on the screen? how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to access.getRootNav() function. I don't know, why the setRoot that I import from NavController is not working to clear the tab. But I read somewhere (I forgot where), that I have to use App. So here is how I do it. I do import "App" from ionic-angular:

```
import { NavController, App } from 'ionic-angular';
```

then I access the `.getRootNav()`, just like my code below:

```
  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
    this._app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPagePage);
  }
```

Then I navigate to my login page, it won't show the tab any more.

Comment: what is `App` and ` this._app.getRootNav()` you have used i am not understanding

Comment: here is the blog that i read http://blog.tangdian.ca/how-to-get-rootnav-in-ionic-2/

Comment: i understood thanks for the info glad you found an solution

Comment: @MohanGopi this._app comes from the constructor ( constructor (public navCtrl: NavController, public _app: App,  ... ). Then you are able to use this._app.getRootNav().setRoot(YOURPAGE);

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks you!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: i did the same this._app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPagePage); but not work for me, still the tab from the first page appear for seconds in the second page

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using different keys for user data in localStorage - 'user' and 'currentUser'
Your logout function is removing item 'user'.
You are checking for item 'currentUser' while setting tabs.

```
    if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") === null) {
  console.log("not logged in");
    this.rootPage = LoginPagePage;
} else {
  console.log("already logged in");
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;
}
```

You will have to check which is the actual key.
Update:
localStorage generally returns a promise not the item itself. You need to check the return type. If so : 
You should be doing

```
localStorage.getItem("currentUser").then(data=>{
        if (data === null) {
      console.log("not logged in");
        this.rootPage = LoginPagePage;
    } else {
      console.log("already logged in");
        this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    }
});
```

Comment: i don't get what you mean, i already added it in my app.component.ts, if i add this.rootpage = loginpagepage to my login page constructor, i will get a forever looping

Comment: sorry if wasnt clear.. i meant the key of user in localstorage..you have 2 different keys for user..1 at logout page and another while setting root page

Comment: oh sorry, already rename it, but it's not affect the tabs i want it gone after logout, the tab still showing on my login screen after logout

Comment: which is the localstorage you are using?

Comment: i am using currentUser key, anyway it's not about the localstorage, i found the solution, check my own answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this i am not sure may be it will work

make your

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPagePage);
```

to this

```
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPagePage);

    or 

    this.navCtrl.pop();
```

> inside your login page remove your header part

and then in your app.module.ts file

make sure hide the `tabsHideOnSubPages=true`

```
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      // Configs for your app
      tabsHideOnSubPages: true
      // ...
    }, {}
  )],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ MyApp ],
  providers: []
})
```

for more information take a look at this page
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

Comment: i use this code this.navCtrl.push(LoginPagePage); it work but it have back button showing up and when we push the back button on the android os button, i can keep going back to the page that shouldn't access without login

Comment: *ps : i added tabsHideOnSubPages: true then i use this code this.navCtrl.push(LoginPagePage); when logged out

Comment: as you can see i have already told to remove the header part of your login page place only `<ion-conten></ion-content>`

Comment: you can try using an overlay check this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/, and also check in the officail website you can check the navcontrall api they have given about tabs

Comment: thank you @mohan gopi, i found the solution, check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here for posterity. This logout function seems to be working for me without any side-effects. Thanks to @uiktiomasfeliz [github-link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5883).

```
cli packages: (/usr/local / lib / node_modules)

@ionic / cli - utils: 1.19 .2
ionic(Ionic CLI): 3.20 .0
global packages:

  cordova(Cordova CLI): 7.1 .0
local packages:

  @ionic / app - scripts: 3.1 .2
Cordova Platforms: android 6.3 .0 ios 4.5 .4
Ionic Framework: ionic - angular 3.9 .2
System:

  ios - deploy: 1.9 .2
Node: v8 .9 .1
npm: 5.7 .1
OS: macOS High Sierra
Xcode: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

```js
async logOut() {
  await this.authProvider.logout();
  await this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('LoginPage');
}
```